# Problem with custom loop navigation inside the blog page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, page-template, 404-error

I have a problem I am not able to solve. I have a custom theme with some custom post types and I need to display an archive for all CPT somewhere in my site. After some reading, I decided that the best solution would be to create a new Page named Blog (slug is 'blog') and assign that page as the blog page in Settings->reading->page for posts. That gives me an URL which is `http://localhost/traveling/blog/` that uses `index.php` file to show the query.

Inside `index.php` i have this:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

            <?php
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/loop', 'blog' );
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

As called above, I have the file `template-parts/loop-blog.php`, which contains only this:

```
<?php
// The Query
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => array(
        'post',
        'travel_tip',
        'city_guide',
        'travel_diary'
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'paged'             => ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
// The Loop
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    
    echo '<div class="stackedposts">';

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
            $wp_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'preview' );
        }

    echo '</div><!-- .stackedposts -->';
    
}

// Pagination
travelblog_the_posts_navigation();

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This calls the file `template-parts/content-preview.php` which has all the markup to display a single post.

This is all working as expected and the first post displays in `http://localhost/traveling/blog/`. Pagination links are also showing up normally. If I raise `posts_per_page`, I can see the posts normally too.

However, the problem is that when clicking on a link from the navigation, to go to, for example, `http://localhost/traveling/blog/page/2/`, it returns a 404 error instead. My guess is that I am missing something that's interfering with the inner Blog page's pagination, but I am not able to find a solution.

I have a similar setup with all the individual CPT archive pages using `archive-travel_diary.php` for example, which are working perfectly and correctly displaying the posts according to the current page.

--

**EDIT**

Just did a quick test...

I completely deleted the 404.php file and the posts are displaying properly in the desired page, but the page title returns Not Found.

Maybe the problem is not in the code from my previous post...

Answer (score 0):

As always, at the very moment you give up, the solution comes before your eyes...

I was using a static page as the posts page, set up in Settings->reading->page for posts. Removing this has solved the problem. Now I have setup a `page-blog.php` template, which I have selected as a template for the Blog page and everything works as expected.